# Apex convert String to JSON

Tags: apex, json

I want to response as a json not string

```
String jsonString =  '{"method": "POST","url": "types","body": {"name": "Ranjit121212","description":"ranjit34443333"}'; 
String accountsJSON = JSON.createGenerator(jsonString)
System.debug(accountsJSON);
```

the above create a string response like

```
3]|DEBUG|"{\"method\": \"POST\",\"relative_url\": \"types\",\"body\": {\"name\": \"Ranjit121212\",\"description\":\"ranjit34443333\"}"
```

But I want to response it as a JSON

Please help.

I am new in Apex. So Please forgive if it is a basic question

Comment: no but I want to should responsean apex json object so  that when I call it in postman it should not give string it should return json

Comment: String is not an json object :))

Comment: Rajarshi Das... ahh  didn't noticed how you generated string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use JSON.serialize() method.

[For reference check here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm)

Comment: ahh that what I am looking for

Comment: sure no question on it